# How to add dynamic column and value in csv using opencsv

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I want to create csv file using opencsv and want to achive in below format.

[image]

Using openCsv for Column no 1 and 2 is easy to implement as header and value can be crated using making POJO class. But for column 3,4 and 5 I want help where **header3/Subheader1,header3/subheader2,and Header4/subheader will be dynamic.** Please help me out how I can add dynamic column and dynamic values in csv using opencsv.

Below code has been written for column1,column2 where column1 and column2 is declared in POJO.

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter("demeo.csv");
    CustomMappingStrategy<Demo> mappingStrategy = new CustomMappingStrategy<>();
    mappingStrategy.setType(Demo.class);
    StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy).build();

    beanToCsv.write(demoList);

    writer.close();
```

Please provide some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do with `Opencsv`. According to their [documentation](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net), you may bind existing bean fields by position or by name, but that's all